# AdSense in a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, adsense

Google recently sent developers a mail, saying that they "are updating our ad policies to allow extensions to monetize through ads". At first I thought this would mean I'm now able to use AdSense in a Chrome Extension, because you know... Google, ads, ... They are kind of related.

However, after looking a bit closer at the matter today, I found the AdSense policy to be the same as before:

> Currently, we don't permit Google ads or AdSense for search boxes to be distributed through software applications including, but not limited to toolbars, browser extensions, and desktop applications. In order to comply with AdSense program policies, please note that Google AdSense code may only be implemented on web-based pages.

So, does that mean Google's encouraging developers to monetize their *Google* Chrome Extensions through ad networks other than *Google* AdSense?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the policies of advertising companies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprising, yes, but correct. From [Google Chrome Web Store Program Policies](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/program_policies):

> Currently, AdSense may not be used to serve ads in Chrome extensions or packaged apps.

Comment: Uhm, wow, they're even mentioning it explicitly. Thanks!

Comment: Here it says its allowed? https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/faq#faq-app-05

Comment: ^ That's for web apps not extensions

Answer (score 1):

AdSense in packaged apps is being worked on. See the discussion here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/chromium-apps/_47r_YKRdjA

In the meantime, star this issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132602